# keep receiving unknown sender emails

Tags: email, gmail

Sorry if this is on the wrong stack, but I don't know where else to ask this...serverfault maybe?

Anyway, for the past month or so, like clockwork I get two emails at 2:29am and 2:30am

The subject is "Thanks & Praise" and the sender is unknown.

Gmail gives no details as to where it originated or anything. Is there something I can do to see where this is coming from?

I know I can make a filter and just junk the mail, but I want to try and learn where this is coming from.